# All possible permutations of 2D array

Tags: java, permute

Yesterday I asked a question which appeared to be a duplicate, this one, however, I am pretty sure is not a duplicate, as this one is a teeny bit more advanced. The title does not explain all of it, so do carry on reading.

Let us pretend we have a 2D array like so:

```
{{true, false}, {true, false}, {true, false}, ...}
```

Now, let us say we would like to loop through all possible permutations of it:

```
{{false, true}, {true, false}, {true, false}, ...}
{{true, false}, {false, true}, {true, false}, ...}
{{true, false}, {true, false}, {false, true}, ...}
{{false, true}, {true, false}, {false, true}, ...}
```

And so forth...

Since this adds a level to it, it seriously confuses my mind. We know that the length of the inner arrays are always two, this will never change. That is:

```
boolean[][] b = new boolean[i][2];
```

What is the best way to accheive all possible permutations of a 2D array, using Java?

Thank you,

Comment: By permutations, do you mean how many ways are there of selecting a set pair of Boolean values in the 2D array, or the number of ways of selecting one from the first column and one in the second?

Comment: All possible ways of selecting false, true, in all possible ways. For example, both the first and second pairs may be false, true. Or all three first. Or the first, second and fourth, and so on..

Comment: Well, in theory, there are 4 permutations for true and false values to form a pair. If you are trying to find how many times each of the four permutations occurs in your array, then you'll have to specifically count the number of times (true,true) occurs in the array. It's not exactly a permutation.

Comment: I see no reason to assume that the two-dimensionality adds any complexity to this problem. This is no different than a "find permutations of a **1D** array" problem. It happens that the 1D array's contents are also arrays, but that does **not** mean that the _contents themselves_ have to undergo an extra level of permutation.

Comment: Are `{ false, true }` and `{ true, false }` the only possible pairs, or could they be `{ false, false }` or `{ true, true }`?

Comment: As we always ask on Stackoverflow (when the asker forgets to inform us from the outset): What have you tried?

Comment: I corrected some of the things I missed during last edit. The two values inside a pair cannot be the same, however multiple pairs can be the same: that is, true, false - true, false.

Comment: As my mind is twisted around completely whenever I try to find a way in it, I have not tried programming a method that works myself.

Comment: I found a way to solve it, apologies for being mad, bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can apparently be done in the same way any other permutation takes place, you need to loop over the list you would like the permutation to be applied to, and go over all possible combinations of the different elements recursively.

```
private void permute(List<List<Boolean>> list, int t)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++)
    {
        Collections.swap(list.get(i), 0, 1);
        permute(list, t + 1);
        Collections.swap(list.get(i), 1, 0);
    }

    if(t == list.size() - 1)
        System.out.println("Another permutation.");
}
```

And that covers the whole things, all of a sudden you have mapped out all possible combinations of the problem explained above.

Now let us assume we have three booleans instead of two to switch in a 2D manner, all of a sudden things get slightly more complicated.

Kind regards,